# How to dynamically map the stored proc return columns,values and types to service class in C#

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core service which calls the stored procedure which returns any number of columns with variable return types , for example If I pass ID as 1 then stored proc can return 10 columns If pass Id as 2 then it could be 30 columns , If I pass Id as 3 then stored proc can return 3 columns . so as stated number of columns and their return types from the Procedure might be always varying. 
So in this situation I can't handle fixed property class in service side.
Once I get the result from the service I will display the records in the UI inside  the kendo grid.
Could you please let me know how I can handle this situation.

Comment: List object perhaps...

Comment: can you explain how I can do that

Comment: [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netcore-3.1) can handle your variable data sets. What you do with it after that can't really be answered with the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bradford, Once I get the result from the service I will display the records in the UI inside using kendo grid.

Comment: Your fixed property class can have mapped attributes for all the columns present in the Db. With each response of the stored proc you will iterate the result set and create a list of the service property class object while  binding only those class attributes which are present in the current result